# ios - what is the effect of having a UINavigationController on segueys?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have an app that uses UIViewControllers for everything pretty much. So far I have been using push segueys when there are either button clicks, or some logic after which I have to show a new screen.

Sometimes it works and sometimes I get strange behavior where the next page loads and gets stuck, and its nav bar area does not load.

I use this code:

```
BusinessController *businessController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessController"];
[self presentModalViewController:businessController animated:YES];
```

I have been reading that I should use the modal seguey possibly, but I am not sure which one is better.

Also, I have been reading that I need to embed my controller in a NavigationConroller if I want to to push, but I am not sure what effects that will have on the rest of my app.

Please help me understand what is the right approach here for me.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're creating segues you ought to use them, either by linking them to a control so that they activate automatically or by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.  (As a general statement, modal controllers are an interruption of program flow while pushed controllers are like a stack you move though back and forth.)

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you - so it feels like I should use the push seguey, I am just doing it incorrectly.  Is my second line incorrect? How should it be?

Comment: If you're trying to use a segue, both lines are incorrect.  How does the `BusinessController` fit into the app?  ...what action should cause it to show its views?  ...what controller is on-screen when you want to switch to this one?

Comment: @PhillipMills a controller that lists the businesses is on the screen first.  Is is called MyBusinessesController.  When a business is selected, I want to redirect the screen to the BusinessController which represents one business.

Comment: I am also looking at something like this [self performSegueWithIdentifer:@"BusinessController" sender:self]; but I get a compile error 'no visible selector for MyBusinessesController' and I am not too sure what that is

Comment: If the list of businesses is in a `UITableView`, just attach the start of the segue to the table cell and let it display without additional code.  (Have you seen this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html ?)

Comment: @PhillipMills I have some logic that gets done before the segue is made inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  So after the logic I am trying to redirect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14821/discussion-between-geekedout-and-phillip-mills)

Comment: @PhillipMills I got it to work. If you would like to, you can post your answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record....

If you're creating segues you ought to use them, either by linking them to a control so that they activate automatically or by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. (As a general statement, modal controllers are an interruption of program flow while pushed controllers are like a stack you move though back and forth.)